# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express Size Limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014-express

I am transferring all of my projects to a newly owned VPS server. I have successfully configured the server and everything works perfect. However, I've learned Express version only have 10 gigs of database limit. Now I am a bit confused in that. 10 Gigabytes of limit is for one single database or all of the database's total size should be under 10 gigabytes? And it says I can actually create 50 different server instances on express version. So even if I have 10 gigs of limit per server, I can actually have 500 gigs of space in total by creating instances?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I Know, It should be 10 gigabytes for one single database not for all, and about your last question, It shouldn't be like this. the limit is 10 gigs for each database and I don't think there is any limit for servers.
and also [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) might help you find out more about this.

Comment: If you are approaching the 10Gb limit, and you have a lot of `varbinary(MAX)` data, you can move those columns to `FILESTREAM`s. They save the binary data in separate files, which do not count towards the 10Gb limit.  See [Enable and configure FILESTREAM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/2014/relational-databases/blob/enable-and-configure-filestream?view=sql-server-2014) and [Migrating VARBINARY(MAX) to FILESTREAM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fa580bd7-9d73-445a-9143-03f173e55586/migration-varbinarymax-to-filestream).